# Random initializations in threads

Tags: java

I am new with threading in Java, and I have a problem that I can`t fix. I have a class Banker which implements the Runnable interface. In the constructor of that class, I am initializing some values randomly, using the Random class. 
The problem is, if I create two threads in main, the values from both of these objects are identical. So if I do:

```
Thread t4=new Thread(casier1);
Thread t5=new Thread(casier2);
t4.start();
t5.start();
```

both objects will have the same values.
I have read that this is happening because every time I use Random(), the values are initialized by clock.
Any ideas on how could I solve this? Thank you.

```
public class Customer {
public Customer(){
    Random rand= new Random();
    serviceTime=Math.floor(rand.nextDouble()*100)*50;
    Random rand2= new Random();
    arrivalTime=rand2.nextDouble();
    //init();
    name=FakeNames.getFakeName();
}
```

Now I know this might be hard to understand, but:

```
Banker casier1=new Banker(waitingList);
 Thread t4=new Thread(casier1);
 Banker casier2=new Banker(waitingList2);
 Thread t5=new Thread(casier1);
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and tell us which version of Java you're using. (IIRC, the parameterless constructor of `Random` changed its behaviour to avoid this being a problem.)

Comment: One solution will be to send the same object of `Random` to all the threads while initializing the `Banker` class. It might work.

Comment: You could also use ThreadLocalRandom if you need different generators on each thread.

Answer (score 1):

Change the constructor of the Runnable to take a random seed as input, as so

```
constructor(long seed, otherVariables...){
    Random random = new Random(seed);
    //Do stuff
}
```

Generate several random seeds in the main function as below

```
Random random = new Random();
long seed1 = random.nextLong();
long seed2 = random.nextLong();

Type casier1 = new Type(seed1, otherArgs);
Type casier2 = new Type(seed2, otherArgs);
Thread t4=new Thread(casier1);
Thread t5=new Thread(casier2);

t4.start();
t5.start();
```

This should guarantee the uniqueness of the random numbers produced by the threads.

Comment: Tried it, same result.                                                                        private static LinkedList<Customer> generateQueue(int nrOfCustomers)                                                                                        {
  LinkedList<Customer> result=new LinkedList<Customer>();
  Random random=new Random();
  long seed=random.nextLong();
  for(int i=0;i<nrOfCustomers;i++){
   result.add(new Customer(seed));
  }
  return result;
 }

Answer (score 0):

If it does not really need to be random, just appear random, use

```
System.getTimeInMillis();
```

always different from the previous value :)

Or use that as a seed for Random:

```
Random r = new Random(System.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the same instance?

```
Random rand = new Random();

Banker casier1 = new Banker(waitingList, rand);
Thread t4 = new Thread(casier1);
Banker casier2 = new Banker(waitingList2, rand);
Thread t5 = new Thread(casier1);
```

Comment: Because I need to generate different values

Comment: It will generate different values for every rand.nextDouble() call.